# How to handle selectedindexchange of a combobox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, combobox

I have Table **Login**

```
id  
name(nchar 30) 
password(nchar 30) 
catagory(nchar 10)
```

and a winForm Login which have a comboBox(name) and a textbox(password) i have following code on SelectedIndex change of the comboBox

```
SqlConnection test = new SqlConnection();
        test.ConnectionString = "Data Source=snipper;Initial Catalog=LoginData;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        String QueryString = "SELECT     Id, name, password, catagory FROM Login WHERE     (Id = "+IdComboBox.SelectedValue +")";
        SqlDataAdapter sqlad = new SqlDataAdapter(QueryString,test);
        test.Open();
        DataSet abc = new DataSet();
        sqlad.Fill(abc);
        test.Close();
        IdComboBox.SelectedValue = abc.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Id"];
        PasswordBox.Text = abc.Tables[0].Rows[0]["password"].ToString();
```

it runs but the problem is when i change the combobox value it's change the password first time but the next time shows wrong password of another record what's wrong with it?

Comment: At first, you don't need the test.Open(); and test.Close(); while using the SqlDataAdapter.Fill() methond, and if you changing the value of the ComboBox, what means changing the Text, it does'n call the SelectedIndexChanged event. Do you have assigned a datasource for IdComboBox?

Comment: Please add code you use to fill the IdComboBox combo box.

Comment: I add the data source through data binding(from properties) this.LoginTableAdapter.Fill(this.loginDataDataSet.Login);

Comment: after removing passordBox.Text code it's working well but throws this exception Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buddy:

Remove the following line. I think after that it may works.

```
IdComboBox.SelectedValue = abc.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Id"];
```